# Simple way to identify the superclass in an implementation file

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In Objective C when ever I am in a .m file looking at an implementation and I see a call to `super` I end up having to go to the header file to look and see what the super class is. This is annoying, is there a way to identify the super class without having to navigate to the header file?

Comment: You can navigate to the method, usually takes you there

Comment: cmd+click on the method bring you to the file, that what your looking for?

Comment: both of those require you to go to the file. Other ide's have the feature of showing you the super class without having to navigate to another file.

Comment: Use another IDE then if you are not comfortable with Xcode.